# JPA query with CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause. How to do?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How can run a query like below with JPA. (It works with plain SQL)

```
SELECT t
FROM table t
WHERE
  (
    CASE WHEN (( ... subquery ... )  IS NULL)
    THEN (t.category IS NULL)
    ELSE (t.viewId = :viewId)
    END
  )
```

I get a `MismatchedTokenException` at `IS`

`THEN (t.category IS NULL)`

Is it possible? Or need I to rewrite this query?

Comment: Why don't you break your condition into some conditions with ANDs and ORs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert your where clause to something like:

```
where
    ((... my first condition ...) and (something is NULL))
    or
    (not (... first condition ...) and (something2 = otherthing))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do that. Have a read of the [JPQL grammar](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html) (here courtesy of OpenJPA). Here are the terms defining the case expression, specifically the general case expression you're using:

- case_expression ::= general_case_expression | simple_case_expression | coalesce_expression | nullif_expression
- general_case_expression ::= CASE when_clause {when_clause}* ELSE scalar_expression END
- when_clause ::= WHEN conditional_expression THEN scalar_expression

The expression on the right-hand side of the `THEN` has to be a `scalar_expression`. Which is to say:

- scalar_expression ::= arithmetic_expression | string_primary | enum_primary | datetime_primary | boolean_primary | case_expression | entity_type_expression

I haven't rooted through the definition of all those terms, but i think they don't include things like `(t.category IS NULL)`, i'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the JPA 2.0 specification final release from here:
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

You should check **Example 6** in **section 6.5.7**.
It shows how to use `case-when` in Criteria API.
I'm not sure, but I think it's possible to use logical expressions (`t.category IS NULL`) in `THEN` block if you use it in a `WHERE` clause.